# UIImagePickerControllerDelegate on iPad on iOS4 crashes (works fine in iOS5)

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios4, photo

I have a problem where accessing the photo library triggers a crash AFTER I have selected the photo.

The log output is:

```
[GEPhotoControllerPopOver respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x239fbf40
```

The crash occurs in Main with no call stack. I only get the above error in the log if I run with Guard Malloc.

GEPhotoControllerPopOver is my Photo Library popover. It seems like something is trying to access it after it is deallocated, but for the life of me I can't figure out what. I set breakpoints in every piece of code that calls GEPhotoControllerPopover and none of it is called after GEPhotoControllerPopover is released.

It is declared like so:

```
@interface GEPhotoControllerPopOver : UIViewController <    UINavigationControllerDelegate, 
                                                        UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,
                                                        UIPopoverControllerDelegate
                                                    > 
{
    char* m_pPixelData;
    int m_photoWidth;
    int m_photoHeight;
    int m_bytesPerPixel;

    GEClient *m_pClient;    
    int m_longEdge;

    UIImage* m_pLevelFrame;
    UIImageView* m_pLevelFrameView;

    UIPopoverController *m_pPopoverController;
}

- (void)UseImage:(UIImage*)theImage:(UIImagePickerController *)picker;
@end
```

The code to get the image from the photo library is:

```
extern UIView *g_glView;

@implementation GEPhotoControllerPopOver


- (id)init
{
    return [super init];
}

- (void)loadView
{   
    [super loadView];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)SelectPhoto
{
    if( [UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary ] )
    {
        self.view = g_glView;

        UIImagePickerController *pImagePicker;

        pImagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

        pImagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

        pImagePicker.delegate = self;

        pImagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *) kUTTypeImage, nil];

        pImagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;

        m_pPopoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:pImagePicker];
        m_pPopoverController.delegate = self;

        [m_pPopoverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(160,160) animated:YES];
        CGRect selectedRect = CGRectMake(0,0,1,1);
        [m_pPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:selectedRect inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

        [pImagePicker release];
    }
}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [m_pPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:true];

    [m_pPopoverController release];
    m_pPopoverController = nil;

    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) {
        UIImage *picture = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

        [self UseImage:picture:picker];     
    }
}
```

I don't think I am doing anything too crazy. I am passing the image data to the rest of my code in UseImage, where I make a copy of it so I am not pointing to the same memory.

I then deallocate GEPhotoControllerPopOver and never call it again. Unfortunately a few frames later and the above error occurs. Only on iPad on iOS4.3. It works great on iPhone (different interface object) and on iPad with iOS3.x and iOS5.x

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

EDIT - It appears that removing the call to [super dealloc] makes the problem go away. Obviously not the best solution but maybe will help in figuring out what is happening? 
I also stepped through the all my code to try and figure out where it is crashing to no avail. It dismisses the popover, goes through a full rendering cycle, finished the draw cycle, then crashes deep in assembly.

**EDIT 2 - The following code no longer crashes on iOS4, but leaks both 32k and 128k of memory.**

32K leak:

```
0 libsystem_c.dylib calloc
1 MusicLibrary MemNewPtrClear
2 MusicLibrary ReadITImageDB
3 MusicLibrary -[MLPhotoLibrary _loadImageLibrary]
4 MusicLibrary -[MLPhotoLibrary albums]
5 PhotoLibrary -[PLPhotoLibrary albums]
6 PhotoLibrary -[PLPhotoLibrary imagePickerAlbums]
7 PhotoLibrary -[PLPhotoLibrary(Utilities) albumsForContentMode:]
8 PhotoLibrary -[PLLibraryViewController _updateAlbumsIfNecessary]
9 PhotoLibrary -[PLLibraryViewController viewWillAppear:]
10 PhotoLibrary -[PLUILibraryViewController viewWillAppear:]
11 UIKit -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:]
12 UIKit -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded]
13 UIKit -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews]
14 QuartzCore -[CALayer layoutSublayers]
15 QuartzCore CALayerLayoutIfNeeded
16 QuartzCore CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*)
17 QuartzCore CA::Transaction::commit()
18 QuartzCore CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long,  void*)
19 CoreFoundation __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
20 CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopDoObservers
21 CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopRun
22 CoreFoundation CFRunLoopRunSpecific
23 CoreFoundation CFRunLoopRunInMode
24 GraphicsServices GSEventRunModal
25 GraphicsServices GSEventRun
26 UIKit UIApplicationMain
```

128K leak:

```
0 libsystem_c.dylib malloc
1 MusicLibrary ReadITImageDB
2 MusicLibrary -[MLPhotoLibrary _loadImageLibrary]
3 MusicLibrary -[MLPhotoLibrary albums]
4 PhotoLibrary -[PLPhotoLibrary albums]
5 PhotoLibrary -[PLPhotoLibrary imagePickerAlbums]
6 PhotoLibrary -[PLPhotoLibrary(Utilities) albumsForContentMode:]
7 PhotoLibrary -[PLLibraryViewController _updateAlbumsIfNecessary]
8 PhotoLibrary -[PLLibraryViewController viewWillAppear:]
9 PhotoLibrary -[PLUILibraryViewController viewWillAppear:]
10 UIKit -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:]
11 UIKit -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded]
12 UIKit -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews]
13 QuartzCore -[CALayer layoutSublayers]
14 QuartzCore CALayerLayoutIfNeeded
15 QuartzCore CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*)
16 QuartzCore CA::Transaction::commit()
17 QuartzCore CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*)
18 CoreFoundation __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
19 CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopDoObservers
20 CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopRun
21 CoreFoundation CFRunLoopRunSpecific
22 CoreFoundation CFRunLoopRunInMode
23 GraphicsServices GSEventRunModal
24 GraphicsServices GSEventRun
25 UIKit UIApplicationMain
```

New code:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [m_pPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:true];

    [m_pPopoverController release];
    m_pPopoverController = nil;

    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) {
        UIImage *picture = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

        [self UseImage:picture:picker];     
    }

    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

//  [picker release]; // <- CAUSES CRASH on BOTH iOS4 and iOS5.
}


- (void)SelectPhoto
{
    if( [UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary ] )
    {
        self.view = g_glView;

        UIImagePickerController *pImagePicker;

        pImagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

        pImagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

        pImagePicker.delegate = self;

        pImagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *) kUTTypeImage, nil];

        pImagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;

        m_pPopoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:pImagePicker];
        m_pPopoverController.delegate = self;

        [m_pPopoverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(160,160) animated:YES];
        CGRect selectedRect = CGRectMake(0,0,1,1);
        [m_pPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:selectedRect inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

        [pImagePicker release];
    }
 }
```

Here is my UseImage code:

```
- (void)UseImage:(UIImage*)theImage:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    CGFloat width, height;

    // if image came from camera, save it to photo library
    if( picker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera )
    {
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(theImage, nil, nil, nil);    
    }

    CGImageRef imageRef = [theImage CGImage];
    width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
    height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);    

    size_t bitsPerPixel = CGImageGetBitsPerPixel( imageRef );

    m_photoWidth = width;
    m_photoHeight = height;
    m_bytesPerPixel = bitsPerPixel / 8;


    CGContextRef cgctx = CreateARGBBitmapContextPopOver(theImage.CGImage, picker.sourceType, m_pClient);
    if (cgctx == NULL) 
    { 
        // error creating context
        return;
    }

    // Get image width, height. We'll use the entire image.
    size_t w = CGImageGetWidth(theImage.CGImage);
    size_t h = CGImageGetHeight(theImage.CGImage);
    CGRect rect = {{0,0},{w,h}}; 

    // set the blend mode so we don't blend into the previous pixels, instead we copy over them.
    CGContextSetBlendMode(cgctx, kCGBlendModeCopy);

    // Draw the image to the bitmap context. Once we draw, the memory 
    // allocated for the context for rendering will then contain the 
    // raw image data in the specified color space.
    CGContextDrawImage(cgctx, rect, theImage.CGImage); 

    // Now we can get a pointer to the image data associated with the bitmap
    // context.
    m_pPixelData = reinterpret_cast<char*>(CGBitmapContextGetData (cgctx));

    m_bytesPerPixel = 4;

    // any client using the photo processing package is required to implement SELECT_PHOTO to its CLIENT_STATE
    m_pClient->SetState( GEClient::LOADING_PHOTO );

    m_pClient->PassPixelDataFromCamera( m_pPixelData, m_photoWidth, m_photoHeight, m_bytesPerPixel );

    // When finished, release the context
    CGContextRelease(cgctx); 
}


CGContextRef CreateARGBBitmapContextPopOver (CGImageRef inImage, UIImagePickerControllerSourceType sourceType, GEClient* pClient )
{
    CGContextRef    context = NULL;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;
    void *          bitmapData;
    int             bitmapByteCount;
    int             bitmapBytesPerRow;

// Get image width, height. We'll use the entire image.
    size_t pixelsWide = CGImageGetWidth(inImage);
    size_t pixelsHigh = CGImageGetHeight(inImage);
    NSLog(@"Camera resolution:%lu x %lu", pixelsWide, pixelsHigh );


    // Declare the number of bytes per row. Each pixel in the bitmap in this
    // example is represented by 4 bytes; 8 bits each of red, green, blue, and
    // alpha.
    bitmapBytesPerRow   = (pixelsWide * 4);
    bitmapByteCount     = (bitmapBytesPerRow * pixelsHigh);

    // Use the generic RGB color space.
    colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    if (colorSpace == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error allocating color space\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    // Allocate memory for image data. This is the destination in memory
    // where any drawing to the bitmap context will be rendered.
    bitmapData = malloc( bitmapByteCount );
    if (bitmapData == NULL) 
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Memory not allocated!");
        CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace );
        return NULL;
    }

    // Create the bitmap context. We want pre-multiplied ARGB, 8-bits 
    // per component. Regardless of what the source image format is 
    // (CMYK, Grayscale, and so on) it will be converted over to the format
    // specified here by CGBitmapContextCreate.
    context = CGBitmapContextCreate (bitmapData,
                                 pixelsWide,
                                 pixelsHigh,
                                 8,      // bits per component
                                 bitmapBytesPerRow,
                                 colorSpace,
                                 kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
    if (context == NULL)
    {
        free (bitmapData);
        fprintf (stderr, "Context not created!");
    }

 // Make sure and release colorspace before returning
    CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace );

    return context;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking a wild stab here.   Your code looks pretty good, I'm tired and might be missing something, but just for testing, remove the line "[pImagePicker release];" and see what happens.   That's not a final recommendation, but worth trying.

I ran into something similar with the image picker and changed where I did the release and it resolved the issue.

Comment: While that does work, it generates two memory leaks, a 32K leak and a 128k leak. I added them to the main question.

Answer (score 0):

Set the popover controller's delegate to nil when you dismiss the popover. I think there's something in the framework code that's trying to access a delegate method in your viewController after it's released. Removing the delegate from the popover solved this problem for me and I was able to release the popover properly. No clue why it only happens on 4, but there you go. Hopefully that solves your problem, even if it's a month later.